# Media Upload URL or URL-loop -Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom gallery slider that I would like to connect to the Media Upload gallery function that's inside the post and pages creator.

The problem is that I cant seem to understand how to get raw URL-loop from the media upload gallery, because if I for now add images with the media upload function, it gives me an output that looks like this.

```
<div id="gallery-1" class="gallery galleryid-81 gallery-columns-9 gallery-size-thumbnail"><dl class="gallery-item">
            <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
                <a href="url.com" title="jay-z+2"><img width="150" height="150" src="#" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt=""></a>
            </dt></dl><dl class="gallery-item">
            <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
                <a href="#" title=""><img width="150" height="150" src="#" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt=""></a>
            </dt></dl><dl class="gallery-item">
            <dt class="gallery-icon landscape">
                <a href="url.com" title=""><img width="150" height="150" src="#" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt=""></a>
            </dt></dl>
</div>
```

And i would like to have something like

```
<img width="150" height="150" src="#" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="">
<img width="150" height="150" src="#" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="">
<img width="150" height="150" src="#" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="">
```

Is this even possible ? I don't really want to use plugins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the url - run a query

```
$query_images_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'image', 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'posts_per_page' => -1,
);

$query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );
$images = array();
foreach ( $query_images->posts as $image) {
    $images[]= wp_get_attachment_url( $image->ID );
}
```

Comment: sorry if im slow, but can you explain more ?
should I add this in my function file ? and how about the images, should I upload them with the media upload create gallery ?
thanks

Comment: this runs a [query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to get all images that are upload in the media section of your wordpress site